# Changing selectioncolor for UITableView grouped

Tags: objective-c

Currently I'm trying to change the background selection color of a grouped UITableViewCell (non-subclassed) with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ...
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];    
}
```

The following problem occurs:

[image]

Also Tried:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width - 17, cell.frame.size.height-3)];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = coolBlue;
        UIBezierPath *rounded;

            rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f)];
        else
            rounded = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.selectedBackgroundView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f)];

        CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView.layer.mask = shape;
```

When I try using the above code part of the bottom of the cell gets cut off when I try to subtract 3 from the height. I'm subtracting 3 pixels in attempt to maintain the separator line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just using:

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

It seems to work for me but my tableView might be set up differently than yours.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've literally been trying to do this for 2 weeks!